# How to get mesh-information from `Plot3D`

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, mesh

In a simple example `Plot3D` shows a triangular mesh:

```
pic = Plot3D[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, Mesh -> All]
```

[image]

I know how to get the point-coordinates and the vertexnormals of this plot:

```
p = pic[[1, 1]][[1]]; (* points*)
n = VertexNormals /. pic[[1, 1]][[3]]; (* vertex normals*)
```

But I didn't get the 2D-elements of the surfaces

```
poly=Cases[Normal[pic], Polygon[pp_ ]  :> pp, All] (*returns  {} *)
```

My questions:

How can I get the element infomation?

Is there a more elegant way to get the informations `p,n,poly` from the plot?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for ``Cases[Normal[pic], Polygon[pp_, _] :> pp, All]``?

Comment: @Domen Thanks, that's it. But the number of polygons (422) is much greater than the number of vertexnormals (249)? What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with `DiscretizeGraphics`?

```
pic = Plot3D[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, Mesh -> All];
DiscretizeGraphics[pic]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, good idea. I can use MeshCells[..,0], MeshCells[..,2] to get points and polygons. Easy transformation back to normalform(coordinates) is not clear to me yet. Besides, I don't understand why there are more polygons than points?